# Ad block won't place correctly

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Basically, I need for the image at the bottom of the page with no text wrapped around it to be in the place of test post 4 (it's going to be a Google Adsense block but I am using images as a placeholder for now). I'm not sure how to do this, right now the code is the following:

```
<div class="google_ad_post">
    <?php if ($count == 3) { ?>
        <br /><img src="****" alt="post ad">
    <?php } ?>

    <?php $count++; ?>
    </div>
```

Yet, the image is still at the bottom of the page. How can I fix this?

Here is the image:

I can't post pictures just yet so the URL to the image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHsd2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have to see your code to help you better with the Scripting Part, but something logical like this should work:

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach( $posts as $post ) : ?>
    <?php if ($count == 3) { ?>
    <div class="google_ad_post">
        <img src="****" alt="post ad">
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>><div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php $count++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. This was the result: http://i.imgur.com/qXiFy.png

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/ZPxBbSXq

Comment: Yeah, you havent implement it. Mine was only an example (: This should work: http://pastebin.com/M0wTirBB

Comment: Still is not working, this is the result: http://d.pr/z4lP It appears the it's displaying the block by row instead of column.